# Is there a tool to mirror input events on one device to multiple devices?

Tags: manual-testing, browser-automation, web-application, cross-browser-testing

I am working on testing a progressive web app. Initially I've tried tools like Browserstack because it's tedious to manually run the same test multiple times on physical phone. Although these tools are mostly good, there are limitations for some advanced features like file uploads and sensor inputs like camera/mic. So, I have an array of about 40 different test phones and tablets that I use for testing.

I'd like to be able to do the following ideally:

1. I manually use one device
2. Any inputs sent to the one device are mirrored so they are also sent to the other 40 devices
3. The UI would update on each of the 40 devices as if they had individually received the input directly

The goal here would be to speed up manual tests for areas that are difficult to automate. Ideally all inputs would be mirrored (touch/gestures, keyboard, rotation, camera, mic, accelerometer), and the tool would work with both iOS and Android.

Does such a framework exist? Or are there any other ways to address testing PWAs with sensor inputs?

Comment: what do you want to test for the camera and mic?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can update sensor inputs in all other mobiles at same time by using one device, because each and every mobile has different sensors and you can  invoke that sensors only from that mobile device.

- try to connect multiple android devices with appium
- join this chat it will help you https://discuss.appium.io/t/using-appium-to-run-tests-on-multiple-physical-devices-at-once/908/6